# How can i nativescript app from restarting when resumed from background?

Tags: android, xml, nativescript

hope this meets you well.

I have this issue with my nativescript app, when the app is minimized and resumed, the page content reloads.

How can i stop that, i'm convinced it has something to do with my AndroidManifest.xml

An example of this issue is

I have a page with radlistview, when i minimize on this page and resume, the listivew reloads and goes back to 0 instead of the scrolling to continue from where it was before i minimized

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="__PACKAGE__"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <application
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden | adjustPan">

        <activity
            android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|locale|uiMode"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">

            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.magnoliyan.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Page.js

```
const HomeViewModel = require("./home-view-model");
exports.pageLoaded = function (args) {
  const page = args.object;
  const homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel();
  page.bindingContext = homeViewModel;
  page.bindingContext.initDataItems();
  page.bindingContext.addMoreItemsFromSource(8);
  statusBar.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue
when the app is minimized and re opened, pageLoaded event is called,

changing from pageLoaded to navigatingTo fixed it

```
exports.onNavigatingTo = function (args) {
  const page = args.object;
  const homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel();
  page.bindingContext = homeViewModel;
  page.bindingContext.initDataItems();
  page.bindingContext.addMoreItemsFromSource(8);
  statusBar.show();
}
```